# What does 'zero of the function will be found within the precision limit ϵ = 10 - 3' mean in this?

Tags: c, limit, precision

Well, the question is; "Write a C code that finds zero of a function y = ax + b, without solving the equation. The zero will be found within the precision limit ϵ = 10 - 3. You'll start at x=0, and move x in the proper direction until |y|< ϵ."

I'm a newbie, to programming, and don't know anything about this ϵ thing either.
Help me out!!

Comment: That's a maths thing, not a programming thing.

Comment: is this homework? You might get some answers if you show us some code you have managed to write on your own so far or if you ask more concrete questions.

Comment: That means that you've found an answer `x` when the following holds true:

`y = ax + b` is in the interval `( -10^(-3), 10^3 ) = ( -0.001 , 0.001 )`

Comment: It means you will find an `x` such that `|y| = |ax + b| < 1.0e-3`.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth & others who have voted to close: this is Numerical Methods 101 and has a lot more to do with programming than with maths. Voting to re-open.

Comment: As Oli said. But I'll give you a short hint anyway: start at `x=0` and `epsilon = 0.001`, enter a loop where you'll increase `x` by some small amount, calculate `y`, and repeat until `y` is between `-epsilon` and `epsilon`. Note that this is not a foolproof method - "some small amount" is not defined, and could be too large so you'll skip across the solution - but if you have problem with this, you'll have more problems with bijection or Newton's method (which are more efficient and reliable).

Comment: @aix: Agreed. However, you would assume that this is covered either in course, textbook for course, or class notes?

Comment: @aix: The OP says they don't know what the epsilon means; that's pure maths (IMO).

Comment: @aix: I got the answer, doesn't matter anyways, thanks..

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: The power of 10 represented by EPSILON is much more related to computing than it is to maths.. I know what it means, just couldn't understand `ϵ = 10 - 3` and what it was doing there... now i do.. :)

Answer (score 4):

It means you have to solve the inequality |ax+b| < 10^-3 by trying different values for x.

Since this is a linear function it's easy. Start with a random number at x and then increase it or decrease it depending on the result of ax+b. I.e. if you move to one direction and the results go more away then you should follow the opposite direction.

You will have to develop an algorithm that decides the increments/decrements of x.

Answer (score 0):

|y| < 10⁻³, or well, -0.001 < y < 0.001.

You must increase or decrease x (starting from 0, as you've said) in order to make y to take a value between -0.001 and 0.001.

About ϵ, a.k.a. epsilon, is used to denote a very small value. For this problem, ϵ denotes a tolerance value, as it's not needed y to take a strict value of 0.